# Событие после повторного выбора файла в input

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Для обработки события, которое возникает после выбора файла, я использую ивент `change`:

```
$('#input-upload-photo').change(function() {
    ...
});
```

Все работает отлично до тех пор, пока я не выбираю файл (или набор файлов), которые выбирал в прошлый раз. В таком случае событие просто не срабатывает, что, конечно, логично из его названия.

Есть ли способ отследить не изменение `input`, а именно выбор файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно удалять выбранное после каждого клика:

```js
$('#input-upload-photo').on('click', function() {
  this.value = "";
});

$('#input-upload-photo').on('change', function() {
  console.log( 'demo' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input-upload-photo" type="file">
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает